# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel' when appending DF's to list, and concating those DF's save to aggregated file with openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I get an error when I want to save the final DataFrame to an excel file:

```
for filename in path.glob('**/*.xlsx'):
[...]
[... omitted code, will share, if interest exists]
[...]
    print('Processing : ' + str(filename))
    try:
        data = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Main Sheet', header=None)
        new_row = pd.DataFrame([[str(filename), str(now)]],
                               index=[0])
        # simply concatenate both dataframes
        data = pd.concat([new_row, data]).reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        appended_data.append(data)
        appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Couldn\'t process ' + str(filename) + ' ! ')
    copy('C:\\Users\\**YOU**\\' + str(filename), (os.path.expanduser(
        '~/') + '\\**CLOUD'))
    os.remove('C:\\Users\\**YOU**\\' + str(filename))

except Exception as e:
    print('Error! Error!: ' + str(e) + str(e.args))
```

after the loop:

```
appended_data.to_excel('appended.xlsx')
book = load_workbook('appended2.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('appended2.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row
appended_data.to_excel(writer, startrow=startrow, index=False, header=False)
writer.save()
```

The "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"
is happening in the second last row here.
I'm confused since the code worked before I made some 'improvements' to the loop..
How can the list be turned into a dataframe?
When I try a simple
    df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
I get a 'All objects passed were None'

---

Some background info:
Dataframes look like this:

Header

```
Eaten this month    Ordered Self-made   Eaten out

Pizza   20  5   7   8
Pasta   10  1   8   1
Sushi   5       0   N/A
Chinese 15  14  1   N/A
```

The header is deleted and the aggregated data has name and date written
Appended Data(final result):

```
Wight    2019/10/28
Pizza   20  5   7   8
Pasta   10  1   8   1
Sushi   5       0   N/A
Chinese 15  14  1   N/A
Olufsson    2019/10/27
Pizza   20  5   7   8
Pasta   10  1   8   1
Sushi   5       0   N/A
Chinese 15  14  1   N/A
```

Comment: looking at `appended_data.append(data)` , i'd assume that appended_data is a list, and list does not have a `to_excel` method 
did you intend to do a `for data in appended_data: ...` ?

Comment: The idea was that the
    'appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, sort=False, ignore_index=True)'
appends the dataframes without needing another loop

Answer (score 1):

I got closer, I had to use append instead of concat. I moved the operation after the loop inside it as well.

```
data = new_row.append(data, ignore_index=True)
            appended_data.append(data)
            try:
                new_append = appended_data.append(data)
            except:
                print('Could\'nt append multiple df\'s')
            try:
                appended_data = pd.concat(new_append.reset_index(drop=True), sort=False, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
            except:
                pass
            df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
            df.to_excel('appended.xlsx')
            book = load_workbook('appended2.xlsx')
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('appended2.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
            writer.book = book
            writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
            startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row
            df.to_excel(writer, startrow=startrow, index=False, header=False)
            writer.save()
```

I still have one issue left:
The dataframes in the final result are written to one cell, which seems odd.
But will manage from here I suppose, something wrong with the indices maybe...